# how do I change the size of a drawable that is on mapview in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview, drawable

Hi I have managed to create a drawable from a path as show here:

```
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
```

but the image that shows up on the map is very large because it is taken from the camera and stored in the SD card is there a way to make the image smaller when viewed on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your purpose to just put an image on the Mapview. If that is the case, why don't you use the BitmapFactory to create a Bitmap from the FileInputStream which you open to your image file.

Then on the Bitmap created by BitmapFactory, you could use the createScaledBitmap method to scale the image and then put it on MapView.

EDIT: Create a BitmapDrawable from the scaled Bitmap.

Comment: well I have a database of image paths and depending on the path that is selected it determines which image would be displayed at the location. would your solution still work?

Comment: @will  Create a BitmapDrawable from the scaled Bitmap.